# Module not found: Can't resolve '@date-io/date-fns'

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, date-fns

I'm using [React Material UI](https://material-ui.com) and I get this error : Module not found: Can't resolve '@date-io/date-fns'.

Here are the dependencies that I have in my package.json file :

```
"dependencies": {
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^2.0.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.5",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "date-fns": "^2.0.0",
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "react-facebook-login": "^4.1.1",
    "react-google-login": "^5.1.14",
    "react-google-maps": "^9.4.5",
    "react-hook-form": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router": "^5.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.0"
  },
```

I tried installing the last version of date-io/date-fns, then tried the version 2.0.0 and version 1.0.0 and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`$ npm i date-fns@next @date-io/date-fns@1.x`
reference:
https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-pickers/issues/240
https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/date-io/issues/33

Reference: https://material-ui-pickers.dev/getting-started/installation#peer-library

> Important: For material-ui-pickers v3 use v1.x version of @date-io
> adapters.

```
npm i @date-io/date-fns@1.x date-fns
// or
npm i @date-io/moment@1.x moment
// or
npm i -s @date-io/luxon@1.x luxon
// or
npm i -s @date-io/dayjs@1.x dayjs
```

Comment: Try reverting @date-io/date-fns to 1.x

Comment: Thank you, I did everything you said and it worked. Just one thing I should mention for anyone who got the same problem and tried @user120242 solution and it didn't solve the problem, just try restarting your local server, that's all I needed to make it work.

Comment: The same works for yarn: `yarn add @date-io/date-fns@1.x date-fns`.

Answer (score 9):

You can check this Commands...

```
yarn add date-fns

or

npm i date-fns
```

Answer (score 0):

In my code, I have used `"import DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/date-fns/build/date-fns-utils"`, which caused `"Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@date-io/date-fns/build/date-fns-utils' ..."` exception.

I have fixed this by importing from @date-io/date-fns'.

```
import DateFnsUtils from '@date-io/date-fns';
```